# How do I validate this form via JavaScript?

Tags: php, javascript, forms, chess

I've done a simple, chess-based hobby project with HTML/CSS/PHP. It lists and displays the possible moves for a given piece based its type, location, and colour. The program doesn't consider any other pieces on the board, though.

http://freemusing.com/chess/

As you can see, the form works fine and has server-side validation. My problem is I'm not familiar enough with JavaScript to translate the server-side validation **[edited for clarity] of the form's two text fields** from scratch. Could somebody help replicate my PHP-validation code **for the two inputs** in JavaScript? I don't want to use any frameworks because I want to be ultimately be well-versed in JS.

- Here's the PHP code for the form: http://pastebin.com/embed_js.php?i=0LRJxkFg
- Here's the PHP code for processing (see lines 76-120) http://pastebin.com/embed_js.php?i=pksn9xPd

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I doubt anyone will to a job that big for free.

Comment: If you've got it working I suggest you use some ajax based validation for it. It saves you the trouble of translating everything in js.

Comment: I should've been more clear; I'm just trying to validate the two input values in JS before the values are submitted. I didn't mean to imply that I want to re-write all of the server-side code in JS (although I want to try that eventually).

Comment: @Ash Burlaczenko is completely right. If someone asked you to convert over 700 lines of code in to something else, would you want to do it? I think it's time to dust off the old Javascript book there buddy.

Comment: Point taken, although I meant 'validation of the two input values' not the actual move-list generation.

Comment: I don't particularly want to read your PHP, if you tell me what you want the validation to do or post some pseudo code I can probably help you.

Answer (score 1):

OK, here's the validation code for the first field. (Written off the cuff, in my head it works but real life sucks sometimes. Plus I'm so used to using jQuery now, it's hard to go back to basics.)

```
var validatePiece = function (value) {
  var legalValues = " p pawn b bishop r rook n knight q queen k king ";
  return legalValues.indexOf(" " + value + " ") !== -1;
};
```

Call it like this:

```
var isPieceValid = validatePiece(document.getElementById("txt-piece").value;
```

You will have to call this in a submit handler for the form. Here's the handler:

```
var validateForm = function () {
  var isPieceValid = validatePiece(document.getElementById("txt-piece").value);
  var isSquareValid = validateSquare(...); 
  return isPieceValid && isSquareValid;
};
```

And change the definition of the form element to call this on submit:

```
<form action="chess_moves.php" method="get" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
```

I leave the display of error messages as an easy exercise for the reader.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. I'll try it this weekend.